# org.scala-sbt sbt-android 0.7 - a lot of errors

Tags: android, scala, sbt

I have an android-scala project, sbt 0.12.4, Scala 2.10.4, JDK 7. I just updated this code to use the version `0.7`

```
#plugins.sbt

addSbtPlugin("org.scala-sbt" % "sbt-android" % "0.7")
```

and got the errors in `Build.scala` such as:

```
  import sbt._
  import Keys._
  import sbtassembly.Plugin._
  import AssemblyKeys._ 
  import sbtandroid.AndroidPlugin._
  import sbtandroid._
  import scalabuff.ScalaBuffPlugin._  


  //1
  lazy val androidAppSettings =
    Project.defaultSettings ++
    assemblySettings ++
    Seq (
      unmanagedClasspath in Runtime <+= (baseDirectory) map { bd => Attributed.blank(bd / "config") }
    ) ++
    AndroidProject.androidSettings ++  // error:  value androidSettings is not a member of object sbtandroid.AndroidProjects.Standard
    TypedResources.settings ++
    AndroidMarketPublish.settings

   //2
     lazy val androidLibrarySettings =
       Project.defaultSettings ++
       assemblySettings++
       androidSettings //error: not found: value androidSettings


  //3
  val proguardSettings = Seq (
     useProguard in Android := true, // error: not found: value androidSettings


  //4
  proguardExclude in Android <<= (proguardExclude in Android, fullClasspath in Runtime) map { (inherited, cp_) => ... //error: not found: value proguardExclude

  //5
  proguardOption in Android := Seq(
    "-dontobfuscate", //error: not found: value proguardOption
```

I googled but didn't find anything useful. Do you have any thoughts?